# Question about Differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was thinking about the definition of differentiability for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$:$f$ is differentiable at a point $\mathbf{a}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if there exists a linear map $Df(\mathbf{a}):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ such that $$\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})-Df(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{h}}{\lVert \mathbf{h}\rVert}=\mathbf{0}.$$ Since $Df(\mathbf{a})$ is a linear map, $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}\frac{Df(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{h}}{\lVert \mathbf{h}\rVert}=\mathbf{0}.$ Then, by the limit laws, I would think that $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})}{\lVert \mathbf{h}\rVert}=\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})-Df(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{h}}{\lVert \mathbf{h}\rVert}+\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}\frac{Df(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{h}}{\lVert \mathbf{h}\rVert}=\mathbf{0}.$ But using my intuition from the single-variable case, this seems wrong. Did I go wrong somewhere, or does my single-variable intuition just not generalize?

Comment: Why is $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{Df(a)h}{\|h\|}=0$? The answer is it’s not in general. For example, suppose $n=m$ and $Df(a)=\text{id}_{\Bbb{R}^n}$ is the identity linear map.

Comment: $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}\frac{L(\mathbf{h})}{\lVert \mathbf{h}\rVert}=\mathbf{0}$ is not true for non-zero linear maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because linear maps are continuous, $\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}}Df(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{0}$. This does not mean that $\lim_{\mathbf{h}\to\mathbf{0}}\frac{Df(\mathbf{a})\mathbf{h}}{\lVert\mathbf{h}\rVert}=\mathbf{0}$.